# Firebase AppInstanceID on IONIC JS Mobile App

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

We have a mobile app (not web app) built on the IONIC framework using JS and we're looking to retrieve the app instance ID. I understand that its been deprecated. However, our stack requires us to utilize it anyway.

What would be the corresponding code snippet used to achieve this in our environment?

```
FirebaseApp.configure()

let appInstanceId = Analytics.appInstanceID()
print("Firebase App Instance ID: \(appInstanceId)")`
```

We attempted the use of installationsID, but was incompatible with our stack.

Comment: Do you mean [Ioni**c** framework](https://ionic.io/)?